# php and mysql script timeout with no errors?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code, it is a script I need to run just 1 time to update a new mysql table I have added,  I have 60,000 users and it ran and added 268 rows, it did not show any errors or anything, it just didnt add the rest and I have no idea why?

```
    <?PHP
require_once "../config/functions.inc.php";

// get users
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM  friend_login';
$result = executequery($sql);   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // get states
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  usstates order by rand() limit 1';
    $state = getSingleResult($sql);
    //convert to lat and long
    $geo = get_geo($state);
    $lat = $geo['Latitude'];
    $long = $geo['Longitude'];

    //insert lat/long into locations table
    $insert = "INSERT INTO friend_location (user_id, lat, `long`) VALUES ('$row[auto_id]', '$lat', '$long')";
    executeQuery($insert);

    echo 'user updated with ' .$state. ' <BR> userID=' .$row[auto_id]. ' <BR><BR><BR>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Comment: this may some crazy but I am new to working on a home server using xampp, I really don't even know where the error log would be located

Comment: Hmm not sure about xampp... maybe ask about it on serverfault :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try setting the maximum script execution time to 0 (infinite):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

If you have display_errors or error_reporting turned off, then you may not see a fatal error generated by a timeout.

Comment: I just tried this, so far so good, its been running for about 5 minutes and has updates about 1k of 60k.  This is gonna take a while, maybe I shouldn't have made it output to the browser, my browser will probably crash

Comment: That's verrrry slow but if this is just a one-off there's not any point optimizing your code

Comment: For the record though: ORDER BY RAND() is slow, doing a query every time around the loop is slow, and inserting individual rows instead of in batches is slow :)

Comment: yes it is! 30 minutes later now and it's only 1/6th done lol I never knew something like this would timeout so fast though, the timeout time must be much smaller on my home server then my production server

Comment: Or use the equivalent set_time_limit(0)